# How to use xpath extractor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Below is a sample response from Jmeter tool

```
        <ns2:Attribute Name="GUID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
            <ns2:AttributeValue>8b0f3dfe-21d3-1035-a063-f6571edcc101</ns2:AttributeValue>
        </ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Attribute Name="SCODES" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
            <ns2:AttributeValue>S0336492^S0309824</ns2:AttributeValue>
        </ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Attribute Name="MODE" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
            <ns2:AttributeValue>2</ns2:AttributeValue>
        </ns2:Attribute>
    </ns2:AttributeStatement>
```

I need to extract "AttributeValue>2" from the response. Tried using regex but that isn't working here. Can we do it with xpath extractor? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried it with Regex and its working fine, whats the problem with regex?you can use this <ns2:AttributeValue>(.*?)<\/ns2:AttributeValue> as the regular expression in your regex and match No. = 3

Comment: some info on Xpath extractor  here https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0

Comment: Hi ararar..I tried with your regex, its able to capture the value but on executing the jmx script with the same regex, its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: the below XPath query isn't guaranteed to work as I need to see full response, next time please provide as much information as you can:

1. Using [local-name function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name) like:

   ```
   //*[local-name()='Attribute']/text()='MODE'/child::*/text()
   ```
2. Using [XPath Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xpath-queries-and-namespaces) functionality:

   - define `ns2` namespace under *namespaces.config* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
   - restart JMeter to pick the property up
   - you should be able to use the following XPath query

     ```
     //Attribute[@Name='MODE']/AttributeValue/text()
     ```

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more information.

Comment: Hi, I used the XPath Namespaces method but it isn't working. To re-iterate, there is a SAML response getting generated on hitting the request. I'm decoding the SAML response to Base64 and then trying to extract "AttributeValue>2" from the decoded response. As the response is too long, unable to paste here. Is there any other method to share the response?